# Bucketing data pulled from a database

Tags: sql, case, netezza

```
case when EXT_EMPL_TERM_DT-EXT_EMPL_STRT_DT  between 0 and 30 
then 1 
else null 
end abcd;
```

this "abcd" here, i dont know where the data bucketed via case statement is supposed to go ie what column, alias ???? the database we are using is nexus , that uses sql to query,
feel free to ask me. something if you dont get the questions

Answer (score 1):

"abcd" is the column alias for the resulting value of this case statement.